# c# get diplay name for every supported language for enum

Tags: c#, enums, localization, internationalization

I'm familiar with how to get the display name from an enum value, basically i'm just using

```
 public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
{
    return enumValue.GetType()
                    .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                    .First()
                    .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
                    .GetName();
}
```

but for my case I need to get all the display names for all the languages my application supports.  I have the below, which works, but I can't imagine it's the best idea:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo currentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
try
{
    foreach (string culture in supportedLanguages)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo newCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture;
        foreach (testEnum e in System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(testEnum)))
        {
            if (reader.Value.ToString() == GetDisplayName(e))
            {
                return e;
            }
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = currentCulture;
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = currentCulture;
}
```

Changing the threads culture back and forth does not seems like a good idea, but maybe it's the only option open to me?  Does anyone have a better idea?

Application is an asp.net MVC application, where i use the web.config

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-US" fileEncoding="utf-8" />
```

to set the current language, which reads the values off of a Resx file.  sample enumeration is:

```
public enum PriorityEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "Unknown", ResourceType = typeof(RootResource))]
    Unknown,
    [Display(Name = "Minor", ResourceType = typeof(RootResource))]
    Minor,
    [Display(Name = "Moderate", ResourceType = typeof(RootResource))]
    Moderate,
    [Display(Name = "Severe", ResourceType = typeof(RootResource))]
    Severe,
    [Display(Name = "Extreme", ResourceType = typeof(RootResource))]
    Extreme
}
```

Comment: How does your application implement supporting languages? Enums? Where if an enum exists for Languages.English then it should be available?

Comment: updated question above to answer your question